# Favicon Not Showing Up In Browser Tab

Tags: html

I'm at a loss for how to get this to work. I've tried just about every trick in the book and nothing seems to work. I've tried clearing my cache, using multiple web browsers, and multiple computers.

Here's the code I'm using. I can browse to this image via the URL just fine.

```
<head>
    <title>Security</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

The icon doesn't appear when I load the site and the Console tab of the Developer Tools isn't giving any error indications.

I've tested on:

- Chrome: Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Firefox: Version 56.0 (64-bit)
- IE: Version 11.0.9600.18793

I also tried generating my own using this website: https://www.favicon-generator.org/

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried serving your site locally at a different port so that it bypasses all possible previous caching by hitting an endpoint that you've never hit before?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps I followed:

- Removed every trace of my previous attempts.
- Went to https://www.favicon-generator.org/ and generated a new set of images.
- Put the images in the following location /Images/Favicon
- Copied the code provided by https://www.favicon-generator.org/ and placed that in my html  section.
- Completely cleared out everything from my Chrome history.
- Closed and reopened Chrome.
- Loaded the website again and it was there finally.